How to Integrate Twilio and Home Assistant for an Emergency Notification System
I have FF-ZWAVE5-ECO Z-Wave fire alarm sound detectors which I would like to integrate with a Twilio notification integration.
What is the step by step procedure to set up a connection between HA and Twilio?


Create a Twilio Account

Twilio --> Account Dashboard --> Develop--> Phone Numbers --> Manage --> Buy A Number

HA --> Settings --> Integrations --> Add Integration --> Twilio --> Copy WebHook URL

Twilio --> Account Dashboard --> Develop--> Phone Numbers --> Manage --> Active Numbers --> Click on purchased number --> Copy the HA WebHook URL into Voice Configuration of Twilio page




Get the SID and Auth token from Twilio




  # Example configuration.yaml entry
  twilio:
    account_sid: ACCOUNT_SID_FROM_TWILIO
    auth_token: AUTH_TOKEN_FROM_TWILIO




Copy the following into HA configuration.yaml file to install Twilio Call Integration (https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/twilio_call/#usage)


  # Example configuration.yaml entry
  notify:
    - name: NOTIFIER_NAME
      platform: twilio_call
      from_number: E164_PHONE_NUMBER


Note the E164 phone number is the purchased Twilio phone number in form "+14155552671 (e.g.)"


Go to HA --> Developer Tools -->YAML --> Click Check Configuration and then Restart to reload configuration.yaml

Afterward HA --> Developer Tools --> Services and notify.NOTIFIER_NAME should be an available service



Troubleshoot:

HA configuration.yaml should look like:



  # Example configuration.yaml entry
  twilio:
    account_sid: <insert from twilio>
    auth_token: <insert from twilio>

  # Example configuration.yaml entry
  notify:
    - name: NOTIFIER_NAME
      platform: twilio_call
      from_number: <purchased twilio number>





Example Automation yaml


  alias: "Dummy Twilio Test"
  trigger:
    - platform: time
      at: "12:00:00"  # Example trigger; replace with your actual trigger
  action:
    - service: notify.twilio_call
      data:
        message: "THIS IS A TEST"
        target:
          - "+1<phone num 1>"
          - "+1<phone num 2>"  # Add more phone numbers as needed






